# How to fix put request from Heroku MEAN stack CRUD App tutorial

Tags: angular, angular-cli, put

I followed this [tutorial from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api#provision-a-mongodb-database) for a MEAN stack CRUD app deployment.  Create, Delete and Get all work.  The only error I am receiving now is from Put.  I am getting a 500 error when trying to update an object and not sure why.  My code is below.

```
//HTML
<div *ngIf="contact" class="row">
...
<button class="btn btn-info" *ngIf="contact._id" (click)="updateContact(contact)">Update</button>

//.ts file
updateContact = (contact: Contact) => {
  var idx = this.getIndexOfContact(contact._id);
  if (idx !== -1) {
   this.contacts[idx] = contact;
   this.selectContact(contact);
  }
  return this.contacts;
}

private getIndexOfContact = (contactId: String) => {
  return this.contacts.findIndex((contact) => {
    return contact._id === contactId;
  });
}

//server.js file
app.put("/api/contacts/:id", function(req, res) {
   var updateDoc = req.body;
   delete updateDoc._id;
   db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)}, updateDoc, function(err, doc) {
   if (err) {
     handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to update contact");
   } else {
     updateDoc._id = req.params.id;
     res.status(200).json(updateDoc);
   }
  });
});
```

My console tells me that at updateContact, contact = undefined. However it definitely is because I can console log it in my Delete and Get requests.  I also get a 500 error afterwards. Their [example site](https://tranquil-shore-75468.herokuapp.com/) also does not allow updates. Looks like they get a 500 error as well.

Answer (score 1):

Which `updateContact` is it undefined? Have you tried logging it at the beginning of each of those methods? Can we see your `ContactDetailComponent`? Once you figure out the solution, please post an answer so that future inquirers will be helped by it.

Edit:
Meant as a comment, mistaken button. Please ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the put request here.  Needed to send the correct params to the updateOne() method and use $set

```
app.put("/api/contacts/:id", function(req, res) {
  var updateDoc = req.body;
  delete updateDoc._id;
  var newValues = { $set: updateDoc};

 db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id: new 
 ObjectID(req.params.id)}, newValues, function(err, doc) {
 if (err) {
   handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to update contact");
  } else {
   updateDoc._id = req.params.id;
   res.status(200).json(updateDoc);
  }
 });
});
```